# Android:Username and password login using httppost

Tags: java, android, authentication

I'm using eclipse and have been trying for a while to do login using http request and php script to connect to the server side.

The problem is when i click the login button nothing happens,my guess is there is a problem with the OnClikListener or the data for the textfield is not been send to the server

Here is my code.

```
public class LogInActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

Button ok,back,exit;
TextView result;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    ok.setOnClickListener(LogInActivity.this);

    result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_result);

}

public void postLoginData() {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/androidRegistration/login.php");

    try {

        EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
        String username = uname.getText().toString();

        EditText pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
        String password = pword.getText().toString();

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        Log.w("LogInActivity", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
        Log.w("LogInActivity", str);

        if(str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
        {
            Log.w("LogInActivity", "TRUE");
            result.setText("Login successful");   
        }else
        {
            Log.w("LogInActivity", "FALSE");
            result.setText(str);                
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} 

private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
            total.append(line); 
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return total;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == ok){
        postLoginData();
    }
}     

}
```

Comment: What is the response that the server gives? (including headers)

Answer (score 0):

You should debug to check if the problem is with the onClick or with the HTTP transport.
Inside onClick I personally wouldn't check view like yours. Not sure if it's working or not but I usually use:

```
if(null != view)switch(view.getId()){
    case R.id.btn_login: postLoginData();break;
}
```

You should try to scope down where the problem is so it's clear what need fixing.
I'd suggest you add Log.d right after you enter onClick to see if the listener is invoke when you click the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `Log.d(TAG, message)` statements to debug your code. The logs can be seen using `adb logcat' or eclipse DDMS. This should tell you the flow of your code. You can also debug using breakpoints in eclipse.

Also, do not perform network I/O in the main loop. Its really bad for you users. Consider using an `AsyncTask`