# How to programmatically log in to a website which asks captcha using java?

Tags: java, authentication, httpclient, captcha

I want to log in to [this](http://evarsity.srmuniv.ac.in/srmswi/usermanager/youLogin.jsp) website programmatically. This site asks for username, password and captcha. I don't know whether it is possible to log in automatically to a website which uses captcha. I searched stackoverflow but I didn't get any solution to this.

This is the JAVASCRIPT function of login button..

```
function submitData(){ 
            document.getElementById('txtSN').value=document.getElementById('txtReg').value;
            document.getElementById('txtPD').value=document.getElementById('txtPw').value;
            if(document.getElementById('txtSN').value == '' || document.getElementById('txtSN').length == 0) {
                alert(' Please Enter Student Register No/Studen ID');
                document.getElementById('txtSN').focus();
                return false;
            }

            if(document.getElementById('txtPD').value == '' || document.getElementById('txtPD').length == 0) {
                alert(' Please Enter Password');
                document.getElementById('txtPD').focus();
                return false;
            }
             if(document.getElementById('txtverifycode').value == '' || document.getElementById('txtverifycode').length == 0) {
                alert(' Please Enter Verification Code');
                document.getElementById('txtverifycode').focus();
                return false;
            }

            document.getElementById('txtPA').value=1;
            document.getElementById('txtReg').value="iamalsouser";
            document.getElementById('txtPw').value="thanksandregards";
            document.getElementById('frmStudentMain').action="http://evarsity.srmuniv.ac.in/srmswi/usermanager/youLogin.jsp";
            document.getElementById('frmStudentMain').submit();
        }
```

Comment: @getlost : why not possible

Comment: because there is no captha recognize algorithm .

Comment: Guess what captchas are for?

Comment: @getlost : Actually I want to create an android app for the website posted. Is it possible to import the captcha from that server in the app and to use that.

Comment: your android app need captha to access the site

Comment: @getlost : okay!! is it possible to import the captcha of that website to andoid app

Comment: @getlost : yeah thats what my question is....I know that we can import....I dont know whether it works??will it works??

Comment: @Gyro Gearless : yeah i know why captchas are for..I think i posted  meaningless question..but please read my comments here to solve my problem..

Comment: i quite don't understand what you are trying to do.you can take the captha code but you need to guess the captha

Comment: @getlost you need to guess the captcha means??

Comment: @getlost i want to login to that website and to extract data and to display it in android mobile.

Comment: so first you need to log in to website .without knowing captha it's not possible.no matter how you going to grab data from website you need 3 things username password and captcha

Comment: @getlost what i am asking is while opening the app it asks for username, password and captcha(actually that webpage is loaded in background but not displayed except captcha).Now user enters all the three credentials and clicks the submit or log in button and it goes to their profile...Is this possible...I think I am clear in this comment

Comment: yes it's possible .you need to search about login to website using http post request .

Comment: @getlost I told you that i am gonna create an android app which asks username password and captcha...now again i have a problem...

Comment: @Kirubakaran what is your problem

Comment: @getlost input fields of username,password and captcha have id...but log in button is actually a image with jsp function...if we click on the image credentials will be verified and required profile will be opened..I dont know how to access this image which acts as button here..

Comment: @getlost if the login button has id it s easy to access via java...right??

Comment: @getlost i have posted the jsp function of log in button...please have a look on that

Comment: @Kirubakaran yes you can click a button .but there is something happens when you hit the button try a addon like firebug(firefox) and see what kind of httprequest send by the broswer .and also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331939/androidusername-and-password-login-using-httppost

Comment: @getlost I cant get the http request..shall I give the link of the website and log in credentials

Comment: @Kirubakaran i'm not much families with android .but the above link i gave you is look same to you

Comment: @getlost I am not asking about android...My question is about using java for programmatically signing in...

Comment: @Kirubakaran yes try it through the example

Comment: @getlost I searched for more times...i cant get required solution

Comment: @Kirubakaran look that too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285250/how-to-log-into-facebook-programmatically-using-java

Comment: @getlost I am requesting you to see that website...Because the problem is log in button is not actually log in button...It doesn't have any id or name...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285250/how-to-log-into-facebook-programmatically-using-java... In this link they were accessed the log in button by name of the source button in the form..thats why I am asking for mail id...

Comment: @Kirubakaran yeah but there is a way .and i looked at your site and yeah there is no id but it's not a problem.it's all about html

Comment: @getlost username, password and captcha is gonna be entered by students...no problem with that

Comment: @getlost now i have a great confident due to you...but till now i dont have idea how to have access to that website...I will wait for your working example

Comment: @getlost have you seen any working example based on my issue

Comment: @getlost okay..thank you so mch

Answer (score 1):

Captcha were made to stop bots from  automatically signing into and spamming a website. You won't find a standard way to get around them or you wouldn't see them used!

Why do you need to log into this? If this is for test automation etc on your own site, then you can build a back door.

If its not your site, then they don't want you logging in automatically. I suggest you respect the designers wishes.

Comment: I want to create an android app for checking attendance. Thats why I posted this question. I noticed that using username and password alone is easy to log in programmatically. Is it possible to import the captcha in android app and getting all the three credentials from the user and using the same to login